# 2つのテーブルからデータを並べ替えるSQLクエリ（MySQL)

Tags: mysql

テーブル A
ID_A, Name_A

テーブル B
ID_B, Name_B, Gender, ID_A

このような2つのデータテーブルから全データ（ID_B, Name_B, Gender, ID_A, Name_A）を並べ替えて取得したいんですが、並べ替え条件が
①Name_B DESC, 
②複数ID_Aがある場合には数の多い順。

COUNT使うと全部のデータが取得できず難航しています。
アドバイス頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

テーブルの相関や求められている結果がよく分からないので、想像での回答なのですが

```
SELECT
  T1.id_b,
  T1.name_b,
  T1.gender,
  T1.id_a,
  T2.name_a,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM table_b T3 WHERE T3.name_b = T1.name_b AND T3.id_a = T1.id_a) AS my_count
FROM
  table_b AS T1
LEFT JOIN
  table_a AS T2 USING(id_a)
ORDER BY
  T1.name_b DESC, my_count DESC;
```

のようにすればよいのではないかと思います

1行1列を返すSELECT句は値として扱うことができることを利用しています